# Typo3 9.5: Deactivate Slugs and use id=123 instead?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I updated from typo3 4.7 to 9.5 - with a fresh installation - and imported my old page tree.

Now the page-URLs and menu-links are "speaking urls" and not the original "index.php?id=123" URLs. But for many of my individual PHP Scripts i need the "old" link-style ...

Is it possible to de-activate the "Slug" URLs, so that all links are just index.php?id=123 , like in the older versions?

Comment: why do you need the id parameter? if your scripts call CMS pages the old URLs still should work. if your scripts evluate the id paramter to detect on which page they are launched you should modernize your concept and expect other parametrisation.

Comment: For the record there are good reasons to not want slug-based URL routing. Without the slugs, performance is improved and links that you generate will be identical to old links you generated, which may be preferable even if the site is able to route old URLs to the right pages. I have multiple clients who prefer this legacy linking strategy for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking urls are only active if a site configuration is set up for your domain. Look for the site configuration module and delete the settings of your site, and clear the cache. Then the old url types should be used again

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deactivate this at all, because the "old" URLs still work.

Comment: The old URLs still work but generating a URL will output the new URL with slugs, unless the site is in NullSite mode - see my answer. Running in NullSite mode generates URLs in the old id=123 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to delete all "Site" configuration, which causes TYPO3 to fall back on "NullSite" mode, which behaves the way you want.